# Can I use the IOS 7 numeric passcode keyboard in my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, keyboard, numeric

I want to do a pin code view for my app like this image:

[image]

It is a custom view ? How can I use this control ?

Comment: No, just create your own

Comment: Or search for one someone else has created...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a standard control.  You'll have to create your own or use a third-party control.  There are a couple available on [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/).